# How comes Spotlight started to show results half in English?

Tags: spotlight, language

I am using High Sierra 10.13.3 and my system language is **definitely** set to Italian:

[image: language settings]

When I want to open the *System Preferences* (which are called *Preferenze di sistema*) I usually open Spotlight and start typing the name:

[image: Spotlight showing English results]

It used to work, but starting a few days ago results are appearing in English, while the rest of the UI is correctly translated.

Why is that? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I’m English and don’t see it as an issue ... :) :) :) but that does seem interesting though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## It's a glitch, just reboot

After a day or so I simply decided to use *the Windows method.* I rebooted and the problem is gone.